# Phone memory full and it shouldn't be

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, motorola-defy

I have a weird problem with my android phone: for some reason, I'm getting a 'Low phone memory' error message, and before getting the message the phone was slow and unresponsive.

I have 2 GB internal storage; in the app manager, it says 1.2Gb used, 27Mb free. Where did the rest of the space go? I noticed this slowdown after installing an app (QR droid) from that Play Market (or whatever name it has now). When I first saw the error message, I had like 100 mb free in the app manager, and each time I reopened it the space was decreasing.

The phone is a Motorola Defy, rooted and using Miui, android version is Gingerbread.

So how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What filled my internal memory were 'tombstones', files located in /data/tombstones, and in total used about 800 MB. After some digging up, I found that these are crash dumps from applications, and are only useful for debugging, so they can be safely removed.

Comment: How did you "safely remove" these files? Can I do this using the default Android features, or do I need an App to do this?

Comment: @StefanLasiewski "Safely removed" meant that they can be removed without causing any problem. You need a file manager (for example ES File Explorer), and I think you also need root access, since you are removing files from the system partition.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wasn't sure if there was a hidden button somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution. Press phone and select keypad. dial *#9900#. A new menu appears. press the second one down "Delete dumpstate/logcat" then just press home to exit.. Done, you'll have bags of extra device memory with no ill effects. Should free up to a gig of device memory, it did on mine.